# access multiple websites which is hosted in a single server via dns name

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, nginx

I have deployed two applications in apache/tomcat) which are running as follows (http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/castag/, http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/filltag/) and I can access as without any problem

but my requirement to,

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/castag/ ------> casstag.abc.com

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/filltag/ -----> filltag.abc.com

to achieve this,

1.add two host A record in dns server

2.I have installed the nginx server and do some changes in server.xml in apache tomcat server

```
   <Context path="/casstag" docBase="/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.45/webapps/casstag" debug="0"
                reloadable="true" cachingAllowed="false"
                allowLinking="true" />
   <Context path="/filltag" docBase="/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.45/webapps/filltag" debug="0"
                reloadable="true" cachingAllowed="false"
                allowLinking="true" />
```

3. create two conf files(castag.conf and filltag.conf) in nginx /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

```
server {
    listen xx.xx.xx.xx:80;
    server_name def.abc.com ;

    root /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.45/webapps;

        location / {
                deny all;
        }

    location /castag/ {
        index index.jsp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/castag/; 
        proxy_redirect  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/castag/  http://casstag.abc.com ;

        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_store     off;

        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        proxy_send_timeout    120;
        proxy_read_timeout    120;

    }
}
```

```
server {

    listen xx.xx.xx.xx:80;
    server_name def.abc.com ;

    root /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.45/webapps;

        location / {
                deny all;
        }
 location /filltag/ {
        index index.jsp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/filltag/; 
        proxy_redirect  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/filltag/  filltag.abc.com ;

        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_store     off;

        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        proxy_send_timeout    120;
        proxy_read_timeout    120;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the nginx.org [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) you have to set the `server_name` for each server. Then you should create multiple servers with different root directories.

Comment: server_name tag added as casstag.abc.com and filltag.abc.com in both castag.conf and filltag.conf  also I added  root /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.45/webapps/casstag  and root /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.45/webapps/casstag/filltag  but no luck